# I need to plot this dam cross section in x,y coordinate space, how do I do so?

Tags: plot

Need to plot in x,y space to test failure surfaces of this dam. See dimensions below. Thank you for your help!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnNnd.png)

Tried to plot certain points and connect with line. Need specific coordinates of each intersection/ definitions of each line.